# iPhone Swift gRPC client gets "Connection refused" from Windows C# gRPC Server

Tags: c#, swift, grpc

I have a gRPC server written in C# running in Windows 10.  I can connect to it and invoke services with a C# gRPC client on the same PC, but when I try to connect from an iPhone running a simple client in Swift, the app reports

```
2021-02-12 12:28:48.639854-0800 grpc-Swift[53758:732067] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
```

I am able to connect from the phone to a Golang server when I run it on the same port on that Windows PC, so it's not a cabling or firewall issue.  What am I missing??

The .proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";
package chat;

option go_package = "github.com/monkrus/grpc-from0;grpc_from0";

message Message{
    string body = 1;
}

service ChatService{
    rpc SayHello(Message) returns (Message) {}
}
```

The c# server:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Chat;
using Grpc.Core;

namespace ChatServer {

    public class ChatServiceImpl : ChatService.ChatServiceBase {
        public override Task<Message> SayHello( Message request, ServerCallContext context ) {
            Message reply = new Message { Body = "Got it!" };
            return Task.FromResult( reply );
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static int port = 2319;

        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            Console.WriteLine( $"Starting Chat Server on port {port}" );
            Server server = new Server {
                Services = { ChatService.BindService( new ChatServiceImpl() ) },
                Ports = { new ServerPort( "localhost", port, ServerCredentials.Insecure ) }
            };
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine( "Server started.  Press any key to exit." );
            Console.ReadKey();
            server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

The iPhone client ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import GRPC

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var client:Chat_ChatServiceClient?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupConnection()
    }
    
    func setupConnection(){
        let eventGroup = PlatformSupport.makeEventLoopGroup(loopCount: 1)
        let channel = ClientConnection.insecure(group: eventGroup).connect(host:
            "192.168.86.44", port: 2319 )
        self.client = Chat_ChatServiceClient(channel: channel)
    }
    
    @IBAction func sendMessage(){
        createMessage()
    }
    
    func createMessage(){
        var message = Chat_Message()
        message.body = "Hello from swift"
        let x = client?.sayHello(message).response
        x?.whenSuccess({ (message) in print("response from server: \(message.body)") })
    }
}
```

The golang server that does work on Windows:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "fmt"
    "go-grpc-tutorial/chat"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println( "Listening on port 2319..." )
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":2319")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to listen on port 2319: %v", err)
    }

    s := chat.Server{}
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    chat.RegisterChatServiceServer(grpcServer, &s)

    if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to serve grpc server over port 2319: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it!  I changed the server initialization from

```
Ports = { new ServerPort( "localhost", port, ServerCredentials.Insecure )
```

to

```
Ports = { new ServerPort( "0.0.0.0", port, ServerCredentials.Insecure )
```

and all works as expected.

It also works if I use the server's IP address on the network of the client - viz "192.168.86.44".  Would love to hear just how this number is interpreted - if "localhost" is a different network than the client? and if "0.0.0.0" is just a wildcard...?

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'm curious, how did you figure this out?

Comment: I tried every possible thing I could think of.  I think I found an example of setting up a server somewhere else that used the 0.0.0.0 address in its configuration, and I just tried it.